# Explain this sentence in layman's terms? (Has to do with hash tables)

Tags: java, hashtable

Context of the sentence:
"A hash table, put simply, is an abstraction of an array that allows any value to be used as an index. While an array requires that indices be integers, a hash table can use a floating-point value, a string, another array, or even a structure as the index. This index is called the key, and the contents of the array element at that index is called the value. So a hash table is a data structure that stores key/value pairs and can be quickly searched by the key.."

**Sentence I need to be explained:**

**"To achieve this magic, a hash table uses a helper function that converts any object into an integral index suitable for subscripting the array."**

^What does this mean in layman's terms? Integral index? Subscripting? Please explain knowing that I don't have any knowledge of how hash tables work, currently trying to understand them.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> a hash table uses a helper function

This is talking about the `hashCode()` function. Every Object in Java has this function.

> that converts any object into an integral index

The `hashCode()` function returns an integer based on the values in the object. For example, a `String`'s hashcode is based on the characters in that `String`.

> suitable for subscripting the array.

That integer can then used as an index into an array.

This is the basics of how a `HashMap` or `Hashtable` works under the hood. You generally don't have to worry about these details, but they are required reading for most Computer Science students at some point or another.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help! When you say "based on the values in the object," your talking about the values in the hash table right?

Comment: @Patrick No. I'm talking about the values in whatever object you're calling the hashCode() function on. For example, "test".hashCode() will return an int based on the fact that the String contains t, e, s, and t. The Hashtable or HashMap will then use that int to store the "test" Object internally in an array.

Comment: So would the "test" object be considered a key, or is "test" entered into the array as a value at index test.hashCode()?

Comment: @Patrick I highly recommend putting together a little example program so you can understand how Hashtables and HashMaps work. But in this example, "test" would be used as a key.

Answer (score 2):

Let us try to understand it with an example - 
Suppose I need a `hashtable` which can store `<Key,Value>` Pair as `<DeptName,DeptObj>`.

So, first i insert a pair as `"Science"`(String key) , `Dept("Science")` (Some dept object).
Now to store this `dept` object program will have to calculate `index` of the `array` so that this object can be stored at that `index`. It applies a method known as `hashcode()` which converts a key (`Science` in our case) to an integer based on its content. Assume `hashcode` for `"Science"` is 1234.
So, `Dept("Science")` will be stored in the array at index 1234.
Now, if i want to insert another element as `English,Dept("English")` it will calculate  `hashcode` for `"English"` (Assume that to be 2345) and store `Dept("English")` in that location (index).

Now, if we go by this we will require a huge array (which will be very sparse and this cannot be realized in practice. 
So, **In Actual** a `Modulus` function is used.
So, when `"Science"` resolves to 1234, it is divide by 16 which results in a modulus of 2 (This is the actual index at which `Dept("Science")` will be stored and same goes for `"English"`.
So, in  nutshell `hashcode` is applied to key which converts it to an integer and then modulus is taken to roll it to the desired boundaries (Which results in collisions also).

Answer (score 0):

it means the hash table key that can be any Object needs to be translated into an integer that can be used as index to an array.  the array item is the value that is associated with the key

Example:

```
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put("name", "Sharon");
```

what is done behind the scene is that "name" is magically translated into an integer (for example 10) and "Sharon" is put into a String[] array at the 10th index
 the magic being that the translation needs to be that a different key will yield different index